# When to salvage legendary items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Should I wait and salvage them when I reach inferno? Does it matter when I salvage unused legendary items?

Comment: Should probably only salvage bad iLvl60 items, and sell the rest (iirc console doesn't have AH so it may not be worth it, but often you find people willing to overpay just because its legendary :/ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter when to salvage. The reward you get for salvaging a legendary is tied to the legendary level :

- Below 60 : a Fiery Brimstone
- Above 60 : a Forgotten Soul

Comment: I'm new to the game. When do you salvage legendaries that have been replaced by better items? I'm a console player so there's no AH. Do you keep them for another character or scrap them for crafting?

Comment: @arno ifyou feel like the item is worth keeping, keep it, otherwise salvage it directly, you don't need to wait